# how to show progress value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progress-bar, progress

[this image after set state progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMq1w.png)I try to use progress bar to show percentage while uploading image but is not working (it's only show on console.log())

```
fileuploadHandler = () => {
const storageRef = fire.storage().ref();
this.state.file.forEach((file) => {
  this.setState({ uploading: true })
  storageRef
    .child(`images/${file.name}`)
    .put(file).then((snapshot) => {
      var uploadTask = storageRef.child(`images/${file.name}`).put(file);
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
      var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      this.setState({progress});
      console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
      switch (snapshot.state) {
        case fire.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
          console.log('Upload is paused');
          break;
        case fire.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
          console.log('Upload is running');
          break;
      }
```

and

```
<div className='container'>
      {this.state.uploading
        ? <div>
          <div className='load-bar' />
          <progress   value = {this.state.progress} min = "0" max="100" id="uploader">0%</progress>
          <br/><br/>
          <span>Uploading: {this.state.uploader}%</span>
          <h3> {this.state.progress} </h3>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `setState` statement.You need to update the `state of progress` with every update.

```
  var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    this.setState({progress});//add this one
```

As no state value update for `progress`,its not showing on UI.

EDIT:

set initial value for progress to `0`

```
this.state = {
    progress : 0
  }
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
uploadTask.on('state_changed',(snapshot)=>{
```

Comment: @BankPongsathorn please accept the answer if its work for you.

Comment: yes, it's work but progress bar is 100% before uploading complete .

Comment: i mean this.setState({progress}); can't use under
 uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){

Comment: Its this binding issue.Check EDIT 2

Comment: ok it's work! thank so much , and next i want to split progressbar for each file uploading because it's use for multiply upload but now it have 1 progress bar , how to fix this problem

Comment: Define Resuable component and pass the each state value separately to it

Comment: can you give me a little example ?

Comment: i try to create Array like this > this.state = {  ArrayProgress: [] } to set value for each progress but i dont know how to set value and increase index to next file upload